# Why are Events not sorted by Date in Manage Events?

Tags: civievent, admin

IN the Manage Events screen (civicrm/event/manage?reset=1) Events aren't sorted by date. They are sorted by the event id descending. If you click on the Date column to sort them by date it only sorts the visible events by date even though you might have 4 pages of events. Is there a reason for this? Would it not make more sense for this screen to sort events by Date Ascending? Also if you select the radio button "Search all or by date range" and enter two dates and hit search it does not return the events within those dates. It just refreshes the screen. Is this a bug?

Civi version 4.6.10 on D7

Comment: Can you mention the Civi version you are using ? Or upgrade to the latest version as I see Date Range to be working fine on the stable release. http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: The demo only has 1 page of events listed in manage events. I have 4 pages spanning from now until 2017. All the 2017 events are listed first and the 2016 events are listed at the end. If I click on the Start date column to sort by that column it only sorts the current page not the entire list. so the 2016 events remain on page 4.